# .htaccess rewrite rule from http://example.com/~something/blabla to http://example.com/blablabla

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Little question with .htaccess rewrite rule..
I want to redirect http request like that:

http://example.com/~something/blabla/blablabla?blabla=blabla

as an request like that:

http://example.com/blabla/blablabla?blabla=blabla

Simply remove the ~something (with can be anything else but with an ~ at beginning...)

I have tried this code but not working at all...:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ~something/(.*) $1 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines should work (this assumes use of a .htaccess file, IIRC you'll need to add a leading slash to the RewriteRule directive if you're doing this in your Apache config file instead):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ~[^/]*/(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R]
```

Either way, the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) are your friends here.

Comment: That's work fine. Thanks a lot :) See you next time and Thanks again that help me a lot ! :)